# Selenium - Locating Child Elem

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbMHQ.png)Novice coder trying to use Python to automate some tasks. I'm not understanding how to go about locating child elements in code. I am trying to have the code click on a link (image), but I keep getting exceptions. How would I select the highlighted element? How does one approach these elements when the nest is even deeper? Do I need to locate the parent first, then follow the children down the path?

I have tried using CLASS_NAME, CSS_SELECTOR, XPATH, but I get errors.

```
main_div_element = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'root')  # <- no errors here
list_element = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'd-lg-block')  # <- this throws the exception
```

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".d-lg-block"}

It is supposed to take me to go to the next page when clicked.

Comment: Can you share the url you are trying to parse, or at least some of the relevant HTML, and which element you are trying to click on?
  Generally, if the element has an id, you can always select it by that.  CLASS_NAME and CSS_SELECTOR are likely to get multiple elements as they aren't required to be unique, and generally aren't.

Comment: Apparently I cannot upload images yet, didn't realize it didn't post on my first post. A link is created instead, please let me know if you can view it.

Comment: Instead of a link to an image, it's better to just paste the code and put it in a code block using the `{}` button in the text editor field, or put three backticks \`\`\` before and after the code to share.

Comment: That being said, the reason for the error isn't clear. There is an element with the requested class (or appears to be) but it's a `div` higher up the tree than the line you have highlighted.  I don't an img or a tag. Do you actually want to select the `li` element, or something inside of it?

Comment: Did you mean copy the HTML? I was able to use the Full XPath to get it to where I need, so I'm working along. Do you have any suggestions on how to approach elements within DIVs, as I understand it, using IDs is best, followed by CLASS_NAMEs, but that only gives the first CLASS_NAME, if it's within a DIV that becomes challenging.

Answer (score 0):

Using `By.CLASS_NAME` as the selector type only works if that's the entire class. It won't work on class segments. Eg. If `class="abc def"`, then you can't use `"abc"` as the `CLASS_NAME`. Instead, use `By.CSS_SELECTOR` with dot notation (Eg. `".abc"`). Here's how it would look in your scenario:

```py
list_element = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.d-lg-block')
```

However, you need to use a more specific selector because that matches more than one element on your web page, and it's not the first match, (only the first matching element is found for `find_element`).